# pgpool2 ip_up config error: socket(::) failed: "Address family not supported by protocol"

Tags: ip, postgresql-9.5, pgpool

I am trying to configure the `if_up_cmd` in pgpool.conf while setting up a prod cluster of PostgreSQL 9.5.14 along with pgpool 4.0.4. Config I am trying to use for this is :

```
'ip_w addr add $_IP_$/32 dev ens192 label ens192:0'
```

I am aware that RHEL7+ does not has eth0 naming convention anymore. I have solved same problem few months back for PostgreSQL 10.7 on similar RHEL (virtual machine) but again I am getting error `Cannot find device "ens192"`
Earlier problem was with eth0 and hence I changed the device/port to `ens192:0` and it worked for me ( still working in that cluster ) but now, on a different machine I am getting error. Should I change the device/port name by appending a digit to existing interfaces. I can see following devices are listed in `ip link` outcome:

- bond0
- bond0.431
- bond0.431:0
- bond0.849
- eno1 to eno5
- eno6d1
- ens1f0
- ens1f1
- lo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question has few dimensions and also the answer.

1. I agree with my earlier observation that `socket(::) failed: “Address family not supported by protocol”` sounds an error and it definitely needs some consideration to solve it or at least some explanation but it does not at all stop pgpool from acquiring vip. Pgpool standard bug tracker also corroborate it. Also in my case, pgpool got vip correctly after receiving the error in the same log file few lines later.
2. Some insights on network interfaces, I found out that the listed interfaces in question are of a physical machine while the machine I configured earlier (ens192 network interface) seem be a virtual one so definitely the network interface schemes are different for both. Although it might be corrected by a linux admin, if one cares to.
3. At last, i was able to fix the problem just by some similar analogy I used earlier. I used the port `bond0.431:1` for vip binding. vip correctly got bind with the interface `bond0.431:1` and I could see it in `ip link` .
4. one more insight, even if the physical rhel machine has the vip binding (a temporary one done earlier not by me but sysadmin) already with another interface `bond0.431:0`, my pgpool was able to bind (and promote) the same vip again with `bond0.431:1`.

Sorry , if above sounds confusing and technically not accurate but probably it helps someone who is trying to setup pgpool cluster. Sadly, pgpool standard documentation does not say much about latest rhel network interface naming scheme and for a non-linux expert it might be tricky on the first place to determine how and with which network interface should be bind.